# Select data from different tables

Tags: mysql, imdb

I am using imdb on my server and am trying to make a search engine for it.

The film must be released less then 11 years apart and must be in the same language.

This would be easy if all the data was in the same table.

title:

```
id|title|release_year
```

movie_info:

```
id|movie_id|info_type|info
```

To get the language you use:

```
select * from movie_info where movie_id = MOVIEID and info_type_id = 8;
```

so how can i combine these 2 statements:

```
select * from title where release_year > 2000 AND release_year < 2010;
select * from movie_info where movie_id = MOVIE ID OF FIRST STATEMENT and info_type_id = 8;
```

If you need more information or if what I'm asking is impossible please say!

Comment: in movie_info, the movie_id field represents the id from the title table, right?

Comment: That's called a `JOIN`. There are so many duplicates that I don't even know which one to choose. [Pick one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+select+from+two+tables).

Comment: "The film must be released less then 11 years apart and must be in the same language."... Sounds like Cross Join... That is going to generate a TON of movies. You need to limit your search further in order to get a useable dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the trick. It's returning the title and movie info from the title table and movie_info tables, respectively. Obviously you can return more columns if you need to.

The left join was selected because it's possible that you'll have movies in the titles database that don't have corresponding data in movie_info. You will definitely want to learn about left joins and inner joins (more on that in a moment) and understand what the difference is. You should probably also double check your data to see how many movies in titles don't have a corresponding record in movie_info. Per RandomSeed in the comments above, yours is a very basic, oft-asked question. I'm going to answer it. But I'm also going to give you some homework while I do so. Look up inner join and left join and decide which one you need for your result set. Also make sure that all of your movies in titles have corresponding records in movie_info. There are plenty of questions on SO to help you along if it's not clear how to do this.

Now, also note that the WHERE condition has been rewritten with BETWEEN. Between is inclusive, so an open interval like yours requires incrementing the years by one. Again, homework. Worth looking this up.

Now, as a bonus tip, I'd recommend running this query with EXPLAIN in front of it. That's important, for performance reasons. You can learn more about that here: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

```
SELECT  t.title AS movie_title, m.info AS movie_information
FROM title AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_info AS m
ON t.id =m.movie_id
WHERE m.info_type_id = 8 
AND t.release_year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2009
;
```